# What does linux system errors, errno 21 mean

Tags: c, unix, errno

#define EISDIR          21      /* Is a directory */

"Is a directory" isn't very helpful when the place I get this error is from `open(destination, O_WRONLY);`

Of course it's a directory that's why im trying to open it...

Comment: Writing the content of a directory? Reading, yes, but not writing. And if you're reading, you don't want to open with `open`. You want to do it with `opendir`.

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for a given system call is meant to list all errors and describe what they indicate.  Indeed, we have "EISDIR: pathname refers to a directory and the access requested
              involved writing (that is, O_WRONLY or O_RDWR is set)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open directories for write mode (`O_WRONLY`), only read (`O_RDONLY`) or search (`O_SEARCH`). All modifications to directories take place through high level functions that either use a pathname or a file descriptor to the directory, but don't need it to be opened for write.

Here, `EISDIR` means "the operation you're trying to perform requires a non-directory, but you tried to perform it on a directory".

Comment: Oh.. hmm.. damn I feel like this makes what I'm trying to do complicated. But at least now I know what the error code means hahah thanks man.

Comment: What could you plausibly have intended to do by opening it for write?

Comment: I was trying to open a directory to paste files and folders from a different directory into.

Comment: @PapaSheng: To do that you need to either `rename`/`renameat` (former only needs a pathname; latter can use a file descriptor, and `O_RDONLY` is fine because permission is evaluated at time of the operation not based on fd mode) into the directory (for moving files on same device) or `open`/`openat` in the directory to make new files and write the contents of the old files to them (for copy or move from a different device).